# How to set picture size, which i try to post to wall?

Tags: php, post, properties, image

I tried to post a picture to user's wall, but I don't know how I can modify the picture size (width, height). I'm using PHP, here is my code:

```
$post = array('access_token' => $token, 
'message'=> '...',
'link'=> 'https://...',
'picture'=> '../..jpg',
'name'=> '...',
'caption'=> '...',
'description'=> '...');  

try{  
$res = $facebook->api('/me/feed','POST',$post);  
} catch (Exception $e){  
echo $e->getMessage();  
}
```

Please help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the question is only about image resizing - how is it related to the facebook?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use something like [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) or [phpThumb()](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks, but i always get an error message: Error messages disabled. (phpThumb)